# How can i connect my Php source with Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-connection

I don't know much about php, but I recently took over a 5 year old php project that others had been working on. I googled and my code seems to be using codeIgniter. I set up apache's .conf file first, mysql connects to the terminal, and sets the settings in database.php. But my php source doesn't seem to find the db. How can I make a successful DB connection?

ps.I'm Korean dev. sorry for my poor English. and I'm Mac user.

I tried : 
1. apache setting 
2. install DB 
3. setting on database.php

1) httpd.conf / apache

```
...
Listen 80
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/edenkang/Documents/joahae"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride ALL
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/Users/edenkang/Documents/joahae"
<Directory "/Users/edenkang/Documents/joahae">
...
```

2) DB / mysql

```
host : localhost
user : root 
password : password
database : mydb
```

3) database.php / codeIgniter

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

when i access to localhost/index.php, it shows error msg.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/Loader.php
Line Number: 346
```

Comment: Are you sure that the mysql-driver for PHP is installed and enabled?

Comment: sure, it is installed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don`t have php-mysql package on the system.If you are using Ubuntu, make sure you have php-mysql installed on system.
You can take reference from this link on how to install.

apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Okay, i will try it. but my computer is mac. is it same on mac too?

Comment: https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/ for MAC